# Panel visibility not changing in C# visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, panel, show-hide

I'm trying to do something that i would think to be rather simple. I have 2 toolstrip items.

test1: ToolStripMenuItem which should show panel -> test_panel_1
test2: ToolStripMenuItem which should show panel -> panel1

test_panel_1 contains button -> panel_1_button1 which should hide test_panel_1 and show test_panel_2

panel1 contains button -> button1 which should hide test_panel2 and then show panel2

However, when I run the code and click on test1ToolStripMenuItem it shows test_panel_1 like it's supposed to, then when i click on panel_1_button_1 it just clears test_panel_1 and doesn't show test_panel_2. And regardless of what I click first, test2ToolStripMenuItem doesn't show panel1 at all.

Here's my code...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace panel_test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void panel_1_button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            test_panel2.Visible = true;
            test_panel_1.Visible = false;
        }

        private void test1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           test_panel_1.Visible = true;
           panel1.Visible = false;
        }

        private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            test_panel_1.Visible = false;
            test_panel2.Visible = true;
        }

        private void test2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            test_panel2.Visible = false;
            panel1.Visible = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.panel1.Visible = false;
            this.panel2.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

and, not sure if this helps, but...

```
namespace panel_test
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.menuStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip();
            this.testToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.test1ToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.test2ToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.test3ToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.test_panel_1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.panel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.test_panel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.panel_1_button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.menuStrip1.SuspendLayout();
            this.test_panel_1.SuspendLayout();
            this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.panel2.SuspendLayout();
            this.test_panel2.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // menuStrip1
            // 
            this.menuStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.testToolStripMenuItem});
            this.menuStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.menuStrip1.Name = "menuStrip1";
            this.menuStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(467, 24);
            this.menuStrip1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.menuStrip1.Text = "menuStrip1";
            // 
            // testToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.testToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.test1ToolStripMenuItem,
            this.test2ToolStripMenuItem,
            this.test3ToolStripMenuItem});
            this.testToolStripMenuItem.Name = "testToolStripMenuItem";
            this.testToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 20);
            this.testToolStripMenuItem.Text = "test";
            // 
            // test1ToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.test1ToolStripMenuItem.Name = "test1ToolStripMenuItem";
            this.test1ToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(99, 22);
            this.test1ToolStripMenuItem.Text = "test1";
            this.test1ToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.test1ToolStripMenuItem_Click);
            // 
            // test2ToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.test2ToolStripMenuItem.Name = "test2ToolStripMenuItem";
            this.test2ToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(99, 22);
            this.test2ToolStripMenuItem.Text = "test2";
            this.test2ToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.test2ToolStripMenuItem_Click);
            // 
            // test3ToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.test3ToolStripMenuItem.Name = "test3ToolStripMenuItem";
            this.test3ToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(99, 22);
            this.test3ToolStripMenuItem.Text = "test3";
            // 
            // test_panel_1
            // 
            this.test_panel_1.Controls.Add(this.test_panel2);
            this.test_panel_1.Controls.Add(this.panel_1_button1);
            this.test_panel_1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.test_panel_1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(44, 28);
            this.test_panel_1.Name = "test_panel_1";
            this.test_panel_1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(442, 317);
            this.test_panel_1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.test_panel_1.Visible = false;
            // 
            // panel1
            // 
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(218, 187);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(328, 318);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.panel1.Visible = false;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(86, 155);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "panel 3 to 4";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click_1);
            // 
            // panel2
            // 
            this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
            this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.label3);
            this.panel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(95, 194);
            this.panel2.Name = "panel2";
            this.panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(398, 260);
            this.panel2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.panel2.Visible = false;
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this.label3.AutoSize = true;
            this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(86, 118);
            this.label3.Name = "label3";
            this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(71, 13);
            this.label3.TabIndex = 0;
            this.label3.Text = "this is panel 4";
            // 
            // test_panel2
            // 
            this.test_panel2.Controls.Add(this.panel2);
            this.test_panel2.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.test_panel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(154, 101);
            this.test_panel2.Name = "test_panel2";
            this.test_panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(358, 237);
            this.test_panel2.TabIndex = 3;
            this.test_panel2.Visible = false;
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.AutoSize = true;
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(70, 118);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(71, 13);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 0;
            this.label2.Text = "this is panel 2";
            // 
            // panel_1_button1
            // 
            this.panel_1_button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(86, 155);
            this.panel_1_button1.Name = "panel_1_button1";
            this.panel_1_button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.panel_1_button1.TabIndex = 2;
            this.panel_1_button1.Text = "button1";
            this.panel_1_button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.panel_1_button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.panel_1_button1_Click);
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 21);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(42, 13);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.label1.Text = "panel 1";
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(467, 357);
            this.Controls.Add(this.test_panel_1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.menuStrip1);
            this.MainMenuStrip = this.menuStrip1;
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.menuStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.menuStrip1.PerformLayout();
            this.test_panel_1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.test_panel_1.PerformLayout();
            this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel2.PerformLayout();
            this.test_panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.test_panel2.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip menuStrip1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem testToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem test1ToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem test2ToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem test3ToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel test_panel_1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel test_panel2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button panel_1_button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    }
}
```

I've toyed with Usercontrols a little, and i like the way i can edit and view them much better than panels; however, i don't know how to control hiding and showing them.

Thanks for the help. I know this must be coding 101, but it's something i haven't quite fully figured out yet.

Comment: Check that your event handlers are getting hit, using some breakpoints. Also check that your panels are not on top of each other. I sometimes set my panels to unusual colours just so I can see things clearly, to make sure things aren't overlapping unexpectedly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your `test_panel_2` is a child of `test_panel_1`. `panel1` is a child of `panel2`. This is likely not what you intended. What's happening is that, because `test_panel_2` is *inside* `test_panel_1`, hiding `test_panel_1` also hides `test_panel_2`. There's a hierarchy there.

There's one or two spots where you set the visibility to false again - I'm not sure if those are correct.

Comment: thanks, i'll give that a try tomorrow. I think you're right though, i did draw the new panel technically within the existing channel, with the intention of it being a child of the form. Is there a better way to go about this using usercontrols or something else? it's hard to edit and manage multiple panels, and im only using 4 in my real app, there must be a better way.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what sort of effect you're going for.

Comment: Well that was a nice way to burn half an hour over some serious head-desking.  I think it's time for some sleep.. nay.. more coffee. :D thanks Charlie!